# Is PayPal aware that in Chinese-speaking countries, the last name precedes the first name?

Tags: paypal

In Taiwan (as well as in most Chinese-speaking countries), the last name precedes the first name (my name in my debit/credit card is written like that). But in my PayPal account, my last name is after my first name.

I couldn't avoid that. The input fields said clearly: first and last name (so I filled them like that).

I'm having some problems verifying my account via the small charge that PayPal makes in order to complete the process (the charge is not showing in my bank statement).

I was wondering if this is the problem. Or is PayPal aware of this, and deals with it automatically? (otherwise a mismatch in the name can cause a problem, I suppose)?

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to Money.SE.  If I understand you correctly you're asking if you should put your surname (family name) into the first name or last name box in the PayPal sign up?

Comment: This question is more of a question for PayPal directly.

Comment: @C. Ross Well, not really. What I'm asking is if PayPal  handles this Chinese format (having the last name before the first name) automatically. Because right now, my PayPal account says something like WAI YING CHEN and in my credit/debit card says CHEN WAI YING. And I'm suspecting that's the problem.

Comment: @Mechaflash Agree, and somebody from PayPal has responded below. :-)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea What were the odds? =/

Comment: If you put the last name first, would that not make it the first name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PayPal is designed to automatically and correctly handle name formatting in Taiwan and other Chinese speaking countries.

We are constantly working to improve localization for all PayPal supported countries.  In some cases, a name may display as (first name, last name) on the PayPal website but this will not affect payment processing or the process for requesting an authorization from a credit/debit card.

As an example, here is a screenshot of our sign-up page for Taiwan which shows that we collect the surname first:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/viQxK.png

To the original poster, the card confirmation charge does not always appear right away.  In some cases, it may take a few days for the credit card issuer to show the charge and the associated confirmation code.

Please feel free to contact us if you have any questions or need further assistance with the confirmation process. We're happy to help! :)  https://www.paypal.com/tw/contactus

- Frank

Comment: Hey, @Frank, what's with the new arbitration policy? Not cool!